# can i backup chromebook before activating dev mode?

Tags: chromebook

I want to do developer mode on my dell 11 3180 and don't want to lose my data can I backup my data to a USB drive(and if yes will it include admin control, just curious), enable dev mode then return my data?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling developer mode on a chromebook will erase all userdata.

While you may already have your Google Account syncing some of your data/settings (chrome history, system settings, etc), local files that are not either on a USB drive or Google Drive will be lost. The `Files` app can be utilised for copying files to another storage device.

After developer mode has been enabled, you will be able to log back into your Google Account and copy back any files that had been backed up.